# Mobile Safari does not accept Century Gothic

Tags: css, fonts, safari

I created this website:

http://imageworkz.asia/sixsensestester

It has a font-family of "Century Gothic" set and it works fine in all browsers except in MOBILE Safari. Take note that it is a MOBILE Safari since the font is good in normal Safari. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can provide fallback fonts in your stack. If nothing else, just fall back to default sans-serif:

```
font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
```

For mobile Safari it's probably whatever Helvetica Apple has licensed. If that's not good enough, do some web searches for "Century Gothic substitute iOS" or just look through the list of fonts available to iOS in order to pick another fallback if Helvetica doesn't work for you. Then it would be:

```
font-family: 'Century Gothic', SomeFont, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

The page does not display Century Gothic on my Android either. Not a big surprise, since mobile devices often have rather limited font repertoires.

Even on Windows systems, Century Gothic is not universal but probably below 90%, see
http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-WindowsResults.shtml